# Create a "Rows" and "Columns" property for Grid Control in WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

as you know, grid in WP8 (and in other platform uses XAML too) use these code to define columns and rows

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Now I want to add a new property to define rows and columns shorter, something like this

```
<local:GridEx
      ColumnMulti={"*","*"}
      RowMulti={"*","*"}  >
</local:GridEx>
```

I just want to know how to add this, I tried one but it didn't work :|

```
public class GridEX : Grid
{
    public GridEX()
    {
        ManipulateColumnMulti(ColumnMulti);
    }

    public void ManipulateColumnMulti(string[] array)
    {
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            if (item.Contains("Auto"))
            {
                ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition()
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto)
                };
                this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);
            }
            else if (item.Contains("*"))
            {
                int length = int.Parse(item.Replace("*",""));
                ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition()
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(length, GridUnitType.Star)
                };                    
                this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);                
            }
            else
            {
                ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition()
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(int.Parse(item))
                };
                this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);
            }                
        }  
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////
    public string[] ColumnMulti
    {
        get { return (string[])GetValue(ColumnMultiProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnMultiProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnMultiProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ColumnMulti",
        typeof(string[]),
        typeof(GridEX),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
    );

    public static string[] GetColumnMulti(UIElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }
        return (string[])element.GetValue(ColumnMultiProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColumnMulti(UIElement element, string[] value)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }

        element.SetValue(ColumnMultiProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a helper class that does exactly that a while ago, check it out on [my blog](http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/shorter-way-grid-definitions/).

Unlike your attempt to subclass `Grid`, my version uses attached properties for that purpose.

Comment: THANKSSSSSS :D worked like a charm :D but I still like to subclass a Grid so I modified some of your code. I also update for other people who need, Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Toni Petrina , I fixed the code and uploaded here for those who need this :D (just the row definition, the same with column)

```
public class CustomGrid : Grid
{        
    /// <summary>
    /// Rows Auto
    /// </summary>
    public string RowsAuto
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(RowsAutoProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowsAutoProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsAutoProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "RowsAuto", typeof(string), typeof(CustomGrid), new PropertyMetadata(RowsAuto_PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void RowsAuto_PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = d as CustomGrid;
        if (d != null)
            grid.RowDefinitions.ManiRows(e.NewValue as string);            
    }
    public static String GetRowsAuto(UIElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }
        return (string)element.GetValue(RowsAutoProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRowsAuto(UIElement element, String value)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }

        element.SetValue(RowsAutoProperty, value);
    }
}

public static class DefinitionExtensions
{
    public static void ManiRows(this RowDefinitionCollection rowDef, string format)
    {

        if (rowDef == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("rowDef nust not be null");
        rowDef.Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(format))
            return;

        string[] value = format.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            if (item.Contains("auto"))
            {
                RowDefinition cd = new RowDefinition()
                {
                    Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto)
                };
                rowDef.Add(cd);
            }
            else if (item.Equals("*"))
            {
                RowDefinition cd = new RowDefinition()
                {
                    Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                };
                rowDef.Add(cd);
            }
            else if (item.EndsWith("*"))
            {
                double length;
                if (double.TryParse(item.Substring(0,item.Length-1),out length))
                {
                    RowDefinition cd = new RowDefinition()
                    {
                        Height = new GridLength(length, GridUnitType.Star)
                    };
                    rowDef.Add(cd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RowDefinition cd = new RowDefinition()
                {
                    Height = new GridLength(double.Parse(item))
                };
                rowDef.Add(cd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With xaml code:

```
<local:CustomGrid RowsAuto="*,auto,40">
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="abc"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="def"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="ghi"/>
        </local:CustomGrid>
```